# Fixing a coulmn in a datafram by a conditon (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set of purchase:

```
ORDER_ID |  BIN | PURCHASE AMOUNT 
1          383218  56.43
2          nan      46
3          3212     56
```

My Task:

> Check on the formatting of the credit card bin data is 6 digits, and if needed, add leading zeros, which may have been lost due to numerical formatting.

I tried
`payments_df['bin'] for num in payments_df['bin']: if len(num)<6: num.zfill(6)`

Comment: Please also include an expected output for your post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
df['BIN'] = (df['BIN']
            .fillna(0)    # to remove nan
            .astype(int)  # to remove decimals
            .astype(str)  # to convert to stirng
            .str.zfill(6) # to zero fill the rows
            )
```

Comment: I think you don't need to use .map(str) here, you can write .astype(int).astype(str), it's "weird" but it works :)

Comment: Nice! I just edited my answer based on your idea. Thanks:)